# How to Un-flatten a smart contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp

how to un-flatten this smart contract?
https://etherscan.io/address/0x789e35a999c443fe6089544056f728239b8ffee7#code

Comment: I need the separate file's code.

Comment: why does it not work for you when its flattened?

Comment: May you help me to un-flatten this smart contract, I have a problem with imported pakages.

Comment: @asdyoua You can start creating a file from each contract and interface. Then you'll have to add the missing imports between contracts until it compiles. It seems like it is something that can be automated.